# example of non linear matrix transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Could you give me an example of non linear transformation matrix? What is the difference between linear and non linear transformation matrix?

Comment: never heard of it. perhaps you can give some background.

Comment: for example is 3D transformation matrix linear?

Comment: Sigh. Where did you get the phrase "nonlinear matrix transformation?" It makes no sense. If it was not in English, give the full original sentence and your best translation.

Comment: i edited my post

Comment: Still makes no sense.

Comment: why it makes no sense? please correct me where i think wrong?

Comment: maybe you meant this   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example. Any 3x3 matrix (using homogeneous coordinates) that represents a translation of 2D points will be a non-linear transformation.  So take the point $(x,y)$ and convert to homogeneous coordinates $(x,y,1)$.  Consider the transformation represented by the matrix:

$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 &  h\\
0 & 1 & k\\
0 & 0 & 1 &
\end{array} \right]$

This transformation will map $(x,y,1)$ to $(x+h, y+k,1)$, which represents the point $(x+h,y+k)$.

$(x,y) \rightarrow (x+h,y+k)$ is a transformation that is not linear, and it is represented by the above matrix.

However, the standard way to represent a transformation with a matrix will always yield a linear transformation.

Comment: Could you give intuition as to why this is non linear? I'm not sure I understand why this is non-linear.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're not studying linear algebra, every transformation given by a matrix is linear. This is easy to see, from the definition of how you view a matrix as a function, namely, for a $n\times m$ matrix $A$ you can have it act on vectors $v$ of length $m$ by multiplication $A(v) = A\cdot v$, but of course it follows from the definition of matrix multiplication that this function is linear.

Comment: what differs if i studying linear algebra?

Comment: I'm saying that if you are studying linear algebra, then every matrix transformation is linear.

Comment: where can we meet with nonlinear transformation matrices? this is exactly the question of my prof.

Comment: Okay well I've never heard of a nonlinear transformation matrix.